# Which is more efficient ? if statement

Tags: c++, c

Which is more efficient

```
if(!var_name)
```

or

```
if(var_name == NULL)
```

Comment: what difference does that make?

Comment: When you ran a benchmark, what did you observe?

Comment: @Neil: arguably the difference it makes is that if it has user-defined type, then the question is absurd because you have no idea what either line does ;-)

Comment: @Steve Good point, but I think in this case we can discount it, as the question is also tagged as C.

Comment: In that case var_name just has to be of a scalar type for the two to be equivalent.

Comment: That's not true - an integer variable containing the value zero is *not* guaranteed to compare equal to a null pointer (yes - there *is* a difference between a 0 literal and an integer variable with the value zero).

Comment: Mmm, I was still thinking of C++. I ignored that NULL isn't necessarily a 0-valued integer expression in C. So if var_name isn't a pointer, `var_name == NULL` may not be equivalent to `var_name == 0`. This is why I don't use NULL unless forced :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both will compile to the same code.  Your choice of which to use should depend on which is most readable.

This version:

```
if(var_name == NULL)
```

should **only** be used when `var_name` is a *pointer*, otherwise you will confuse anyone who reads your code in the future.  Some compilers might complain if you use this on a non-pointer.

This one:

```
if(!var_name)
```

should be used in cases when you are logically treating `var_name` as a *boolean* (true/false) value.  This can include when `var_name` is a pointer, since `NULL` is the value for "false" or undefined pointers.

If `var_name` is an integer, then I would choose a third option:

```
if(var_name == 0)
```

as I find it expresses intent more clearly.

Comment: Actually, they may compile to different assembly language instructions, depends on the processor.  Some processors may have a *Jump If Not Equal* (*Jump If Not Zero*) some may not.  In either case, this is a trivial optimization compared to requirements or design optimizations.  Optimizations at this level are platform specific.

Comment: Equallity and inequallity operators are said to generally be equally faster :)

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter. Both will be very efficient, no matter what compiler you use, and for most compilers will compile to exactly the same code. If this is of genuine concern to you, take a look at the assembly/machine code emitted by your specific compiler.

Comment: And I doubt that any potential difference will ever be significant.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: It can heavily depend on the comppiler and the requirements. Really if one cares so much he should look into the disassembly.

Answer (score 5):

It does not matter.

Changing this would be [micro optimisation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000185.html) and unlikely to change the performance of your app (unless you have actualy checked this is the bottle neck).
Other then that I would bet the compiler would change this statement into the best one (if it mattered), so I would use the syntax that you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The first. It's 7 characters shorter.

Comment: ... no. Just no. Number of characters != readability or better. Let's see, which one tells me more, `dlsym` or `GetProcAddress`?

Comment: My point was that the only difference between the two was the number of characters they take, and that there's no difference to the compiler, much like differences in whitespace... using a play on the meaning of "efficient". I happen to like the first a lot better but it's certainly a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

In case var_name is a pointer and you're compiling for some embedded system with a crappy non-optimizing compiler, `var_name == NULL` will be faster, because a cast to boolean followed by negation followed by comparison to true will be slower than plain value comparison. In case of about every single other compiler they will get optimized away to the same code.

Comment: Obviously a crappy non-optimising compiler can make a horlicks of any code it likes, but 6.5.3.3/5 of n1256 says, "The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E)". So it's not just negligence, a C compiler actually has to go out of its way for the ! operator to produce code that converts to boolean type and then compares to true, since that isn't how the ! operator is defined. Could be different in C++, I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

If 'var' is of a UDT, then the choice of which to use would be guided more by which of these operators the class offers rather than efficiency (which I believe is answered by most of the responses above)

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent in the view of efficiency but later is better for readability,which also play crucial role in coding.

Answer (score -1):

I would not use a compiler which generates different code for performance sensitive stuff.